# Using CDK diff to diff resources wrapped in a pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli, aws-cdk

I have a CDK project where we wrap all our resources in the Pipeline construct. Prior to adding the pipeline, we could run cdk diff locally to view changes to the resources we were deploying. Now that we use the Pipeline construct, running diff's locally only results in changes to the pipeline construct being displayed. Is there any way other fiddling with the pipeline construct to view diff's of the application resources and not the pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option 1:  diff the Application resources AND the Pipeline resources

The [stack specifier](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cli.html#cli-stacks) `**` will return differences for all stacks in the hierarchy, not just the Pipeline itself:

```bash
cdk diff '**' -a 'ts-node ./bin/app-pipeline.ts'
```

#### Option 2: diff the Application resources only

To exclude differences in your Pipeline stack entirely, first nest the "application' stacks in a new `Construct` subclass.  See CDK doc's `MyService` construct [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/stacks.html). `MyService` wraps three child "application" stacks:

```yaml
MyService           # Construct
    ControlPlane    # Stack
    DataPlane       # Stack
    Monitoring      # Stack
```

Then use `MyService` in two contexts, your pipeline Stage and App:

```yaml
# app-pipeline.ts
MyPipeline          # Pipeline
    MyStage         # Stage
        MyService   # Construct

# app.ts
App                 # App
    MyService       # Construct
```

Running `cdk diff --app 'ts-node ./bin/app.ts'` on the App will generate the differences in `ControlPlane`, `DataPlane` and `Monitoring`, not the pipeline itself.  These are the same Application differences that will be deployed in the pipeline.